# How to click on an element in case of not unique id in Robot Framework Selenium

Tags: python, robotframework, element

For Example code:

```
    <tr class="list-surveyor-assign" data-id="xoghSatJFCJ">
<td style="width: 40%><p style="padding-bottom: 5px;">Miss Anna</p></td>
    <button id="btnSelectSurveyor" title="Assign" class="btn btn-sm btn-primary" data-surveyor="xoghSatJFCJ">
        <i class="fa fa-user-plus" aria-hidden="true"></i>
    </button>
</tr>
<tr class="list-surveyor-assign" data-id="7G8s7AwTzkh">
<td style="width: 40%><p style="padding-bottom: 5px;">Miss Jane</p></td>
    <button id="btnSelectSurveyor" title="Assign" class="btn btn-sm btn-primary" data-surveyor="7G8s7AwTzkh">
        <i class="fa fa-user-plus" aria-hidden="true"></i>
    </button>
```

**How to click on button**
id="btnSelectSurveyor" with data-surveyor="7G8s7AwTzkh"

Comment: Why do you modify my edition?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can make use of two individual attributes such as below.

> `//button[@id='btnSelectSurveryor' and title='Assign']`

Comment: But title is not unique too, I try to click on element id="btnSelectSurveyor" and data-surveyor="7G8s7AwTzkh"

Comment: I have already solved it. xpath=//Button[@id="btnSelectSurveyor" and @data-surveyor="7G8s7AwTzkh"]

Comment: Great using 'and' with unique attributes should do the trick. Kindly close the question and mark the answer as helpful if it did.